# Searching after group by on javascript object using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jsfiddle below.I would like to do some searching on this return javascript object(ie. byJob).

http://jsfiddle.net/ravice70/2yUuT/

For example if user select id 2 it will display like this. All other record should be delete.

2,2

2, test group 1

2, test group 1

Anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You have this filed under `jQuery`, but your fiddle uses `MooTools`. Did you misfile this, or is the fiddle wrong?

Comment: you can change to jquery. i guess when i saved it i forget to change to jquery.